# cvxopt DLL load failed

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, cvxopt

I have been trying to use the cvxopt package in my IntelliJ program.

It gives me the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\cvxopt\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    import cvxopt.base
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32-application.
```

I googled the problem but didn't find anything yet. I would be grateful some help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is likely to happen if you have the wrong version of numpy in your machine. Many binaries depend on numpy+mkl hence try to install the appropriate version of numpy+mkl, that will likely solve your problem